# @ConstructorResult mapping in JPA 2.1 does not work properly with Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I try to map a native query to a non-Entity class. I have the following Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "groupList", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = GroupListEntry.class, columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "typeId", type = Long.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "lastUpdateDate", type = Date.class)
    })
})
public class GroupEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

I expected that calling

```java
final Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(q.toString(), "groupList");
final List<GroupListEntry> result = Collections.checkedList(query.getResultList(), GroupListEntry.class);
```

will result in creating `GroupListEntry` objects using the following constructor (as it is described in `@ColumnResult` annotations)

```java
public GroupListEntry(
        final Long groupId,
        final String name,
        final Long typeId,
        final Date lastUpdateDate) {
    ...
}
```

but it turned out that the expected constructor is dependent on the underlying database...
In integration tests I use HSQLDB and JPA/Hibernate tries to call:

```java
public GroupListEntry(
        final BigInteger groupId,
        final String name,
        final BigInteger typeId,
        final Date lastUpdateDate) {
    ...
}
```

whereas on a development environment, where MSSQL is used, it calls:

```java
public GroupListEntry(
        final Integer groupId,
        final String name,
        final Integer typeId,
        final Date lastUpdateDate) {
    ...
}
```

Apparently the specified type in each `@ColumnResult` is simply ignored. I want to have only one constructor instead of three.

Below is a fragment of my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am I missing something?

Writing some annotations is much more elegant than manual mapping after executing a query, but I cannot force it to work properly.

Regards,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that your expectation was correct, namely the following is true for Hibernate 4.3.5:

> Apparently the specified type in each @ColumnResult is simply ignored.

There is an official Hibernate bug for this: [HHH-8237 - Type mapping of @ColumnResult is ignored](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8237). As you can see there, this bug was fixed in Hibernate version 4.3.6.

Comment: I don't remember how I've resolved it, but anyway thanks for your answer!