# Getting "Could not locate appropriate constructor on class" when result contains LocalDateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Like the title says, I'm getting "Could not locate appropriate constructor on class".

Here's my result set mapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MyMapping", classes = { 
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MyClass.class, columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "my_date", type = LocalDateTime.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "label", type = String.class) }) })
```

Here's my constructor

```
public MyClass(LocalDateTime myDate, String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.myDate= myDate;
    }
```

If I cast the timestamp as a VarChar in my sql statment and change the mapping and variables to a String, everything works. So I'm assuming the mapping does not like LocalDateTime.class.

I've also commented out the sqlQuery.setResultSetMapping and stepped through the code  and confirmed that the types look correct correct.

database is postgresql

Changed from Hibernate 4 to 5 and now it works. Unfortunately, moving to Hibernate 5 would require a lot of work so not sure if there is a solution. I may just have to map as a string and convert it to LocalDateTime

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, what exact version of Hibernate 4 do you use?

Comment: @PetrBodnár 4.3.1.Final

Comment: Then the problem you have is most probably fixed in 4.3.6 (as well as in 5.x) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761770/constructorresult-mapping-in-jpa-2-1-does-not-work-properly-with-hibernate-4-3/59001641#59001641. So I guess this question will be a kinda duplicate...

Comment: @PetrBodnár agreed. So maybe it's with any Date types? Either way I just mapped it as a String and converted later.

Comment: thx for the confirmation... I would rather say with *any* type. Because the older versions of Hibernate simply ignore the `type` attribute...